# ValueError: time data does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'

Tags: python, python-datetime, valueerror

> I am writing this code to change the type of "Gmt time" column. But, I give "ValueError: time data does not match format ". How could I convert to float or someother types except Object and string?
>
> My code is:

```
path= '/content/drive/MyDrive/H1_ASK_Raw.csv'
dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
df = pd.read_csv(path,sep=',', index_col='Date', parse_dates=['Gmt time'], date_parser=dateparse).fillna(0)
df.head()
```

> I get the below Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/base_parser.py in converter(*date_cols)
1038                 result = tools.to_datetime(
-> 1039                     date_parser(*date_cols), errors="ignore", cache=cache_dates
1040                 )

                                 18 frames
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not numpy.ndarray

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 ValueError: time data '05.05.2003 00:00:00.000' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 /usr/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
 357     if not found:
 358         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
 --> 359                          (data_string, format))
 360     if len(data_string) != found.end():
 361         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

 ValueError: time data '05.05.2003 00:00:00.000' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Comment: Are you sure month and day isn't reversed?

Comment: Yes! I tried  '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f' and  '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f' both.

Comment: The time you are trying to parse (`05.05.2003 ...`) has `.` characters between the date components, but the format string `%m/%d/%Y ...` has `/` characters. You are getting an error message saying that the time doesn't match the format because the time indeed doesn't match the format.

Comment: thats right!!!!!! thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0):

make 2 argument

```
stock['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(stock['Date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')

stock['Date_ts'] = pd.to_datetime(stock['Date_ts']).dt.strftime('%m-%d-%y')
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.